# IOS BLE - Why can`t I recieve all the data from peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I`m building an app that receives data from custom BLE device continuously and sometimes the app misses some data? the connection persists(no disconnection occurs) but some data is being missed.
How can that be? does the BLE protocol guarantee that the master will receive all the data?
How can I improve that and make sure that all data will be received?

Comment: Do you have any more info on what is going on? Did you make some protocol where you sequentially request for packages that you then stitch together where some packages seem to be missing? Or is `value` on your characteristic missing some data?

Comment: I enable a characteristic notification and then the device start sending data all the time until closing the app...

Comment: The data is being sent for hours

Comment: It is possible that the device is updating the values too quickly. How we usually do it (Or at least in my experience) is that receiver (the phone) triggers the update on characteristic using a write command on another characteristic. So basically the whole operation is `write:readyForMoreData -> waitNotification -> readData -> write:readyForMoreData -> waitNotification -> readData...`

Comment: @MaticOblak So why sometimes the app manages to get all the data and randomly not?

Comment: This is just a guess but if the sender has no way of telling if receiver did in fact receive all data then receiver may still get all data in most cases. But pretty much any glitch may produce packet loss; it can be network related, app being stalled related or even iOS stalled. Maybe another BT device is found and some data exchange is done which stalls the transfer.

Comment: I haven't seen notifications being dropped by iOS EXCEPT when you don't have background capabilities enabled for the app, and the app is suspended.

Comment: You probably have a threadsafety issue but without sharing any code we can only speculate. IOS re-uses the characteristic objects and the value is overwritten every time you receive a notification. So make sure you make a copy of the value immediately when receiving the notification

Comment: @MartijnvanWelie Can you please provide some code example for achieving this goal?